# selenium 'webdriver' not being recognised (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I have installed selenium through python using pip (I ran):

```
pip install selenium
```

I'm using Python 3.9.0 and the driver argument isn't being recognized.

My current code.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
filepath = r"D:\msedgedriver.exe"
webdriver.Edge(filepath)
options=driver.EdgeOptions()
```

In this code. there is no issue with the import command but `driver` is not being recognised as valid syntax.

Any help?

Comment: Same applies here 
```driver.get('url')```

Comment: are you using pycham?

Comment: I'm not using pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the command below to install the MS Edge Selenium tools:

```
pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
```

Then use the code below, it can work well on my side:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
driver = Edge(options = edge_options, executable_path = r"D:\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://microsoft.com')
```

Please note to use the same version of Edge Webdriver as the Edge browser and change the paths in the code to your owns.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [Enhancing automated testing in Microsoft Edge with new WebDriver capabilities, W3C protocol support, and automatic updates](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97), now MicrosoftWebDriver is a [Windows Feature on Demand (FoD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities), which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically, and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

---

### Steps

- Enable Developer Mode which will install the appropriate version of WebDriver.

  ```
  Open Settings app > Go to Update & Security > For Developer and then select "Developer Mode".
  ```
- You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:
- Search "Manage optional features" from Start, then select "Add a Feature", "WebDriver".
- Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

  ```
  DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
  ```

**Note**: When installing *MicrosoftWebDriver* through the `DISM` command, by default the webdriver is installed within the following sub-directories:

- 64 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```
- 32 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```

---

### Usage

You can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly error using EdgeDriver and Microsoft Edge in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471353/microsoft-web-driver-has-stopped-working-a-problem-cause-the-program-to-stop-wo/59473613#59473613)
- [MicrosoftWebDriver.exe should be pre-installed in an elevated command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447561/microsoftwebdriver-exe-should-be-pre-installed-in-an-elevated-command-prompt/59447890#59447890)
- [MicrosoftWebDriver loading web driver null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746468/microsoftwebdriver-loading-web-driver-null/46769675#46769675)
- [Selenium RemoteWebDriver UnreachableBrowserException with Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201395/selenium-remotewebdriver-unreachablebrowserexception-with-edge/49202742#49202742)

---

### tl; dr

As per [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).